# Ruby on Rails - Checking if Submitted Form Data matches Database data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in which a user ('member') submits a 4-digit pin, which is then saved to a session variable called `:submitted_pin`. For some reason, the quick if/else statement isn't working properly, and I am assuming it is a silly mistake on my part, but if your willing to take a look I would really appreciate it!

**View**

```
<%= form_for :member_pin, :url => { :action => "verify_pin", :id => member.id } do |f| %>`
  <%= f.label :pin %>
  <%= f.text_field :pin %>
<%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
```

**Controller**

*Before Filter*

```
before_filter :validate_pin, :only => :show
```

*Action (POST Route)*

```
def verify_pin
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])

  session[:submitted_pin] = params[:member_pin][:pin]
  redirect_to @member
end
```

*Filter*

```
def validate_pin
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  @member_pin = @member.pin

  if session[:submitted_pin] == @member_pin
    render @member
  else
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

And the result of all of this is a redirect to my root_url no matter what, even if the Pin entered *does* match the pin in the database for that user. Help! Thanks :)

Comment: In your `validate_pin` method, right above your if statement, add this line: `raise "#{@member_pin} == #{session[:submitted_pin]}: #{@member_pin == session[:submitted_pin]}"` and that will give you three pieces of data: the session variable submitted_pin as understood by Rails, the member.pin as understood by Rails, and their equivalency. If I had to venture a guess from a standing start, I'd bet that one is a string and the other is an integer - that screws me up all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It looks like you're right... one must be a string and one must be an integer. This is what I am getting from the `raise` method you wrote me! `5555 == 5555: false` -- How would I go about converting `to_i` or `to_s` in my code I provided in my question?

Comment: Perfect! There's a couple ways to go from here: the simplest is to set `.to_i` on each of the items you're comparing, that way you don't have to care which is which. The other method would be to use `.inspect` or `.class` on each of your data points, to figure out which piece is what, and then use a converter such as `.to_i` to convert only the one you need. One of those ought to do the trick!

Comment: Best way to troubleshoot this is by writing a controller test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the results of the raise we talked about in the comments, it sounds like there's a class mismatch. The easiest way to fix (and, IMHO, the easiest to read) would be to adjust your validator code as follows:

```
if session[:submitted_pin].to_i == @member_pin.to_i
  render @member
else
  redirect_to '/'
end
```

If there's any chance that `session[:submitted_pin]` would be `nil`, you can use `session[:submitted_pin].try(:to_i)`; that'll return `nil` if the variable is not set and prevent an error from getting thrown.

Comment: Yikes! I got this error: `undefined method 'pin' for 5555:Fixnum`

Comment: I should also mention -- that error is being called on the `<%= f.text_field :pin %>` part of my View. Any ideas? :/